# Request failed; 0-111 No error; Connection refused when calling Parse.Cloud.httpRequest

Tags: parse-platform

I am getting the error: **Request failed; 0-111 No error; Connection refused** when calling Parse.Cloud.httpRequest with a big body.

That is my code:

> ```
> var retPrm = new Parse.Promise();
> Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
>     method: "POST",
>     url: "https://SOMEURL/integration_io.asmx",
>     headers: {"Content-Type":"text/xml"},
>     body: body,
>     success: function(httpResponse) { retPrm.resolve(httpResponse); },
>     error:   function(httpResponse) { retPrm.reject( httpResponse); }
> });
> return retPrm;
> ```

I think the body is the problem. It is a SOAP Envelop, very ugly, and big. It has  32,455 bytes. Of course, when I run the same function with a 1,144 bytes body, it runs like a charm.

Any hints?

Thanks,

Oscar

Comment: I had the same problem. When the body of my request was bigger than a certain limit, it began throwing this same error! Did you find a work around?

Comment: No, unfortunately. I asked my customer to use a smaller timeframe of information. However, there is a bug filled in Parse. They are analyzing.

Comment: That's the bug filled there: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/417492765115443/